# Toggle not showing container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a system made up to toggle different sections. It works pretty much how I want it, except for some reason all of the content within the div `project-name-block-container` does not show when I click on the different blocks. The images show in the first block, but that's it. Shouldn't all of the content show since I wrapped all of it with a div?

Also is there a way to keep the functionality of what I have the same, except change one thing. instead of being able to click in the `project-name-block` to toggle the blocks, is there a way to make it where the user has to click the title?

```js
var allPanels = $('.project-name-block-container').hide();
//$('.project-name-block:eq(0) .project-name-description').show();
$('.project-name-block').click(function() {
  allPanels.slideUp();
  $(this).children('.project-name-block-container').slideDown();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#project-section-container {
  height: auto;
}
.project-name-block {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.project-name-title {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.project-name-description {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
/*.project-name-description.active {
 display: block;
}*/

/*--Project Images---*/

.project-image-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px 5%;
}
.project-img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 1</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 1</div>
    <div class="project-image-container">
      <img src="images/projects/project1.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
      <img src="images/projects/project2.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 2</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 3</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 4</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 5</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `display:none` for the description ... remove that

```
 .project-name-description {
    /*display: none;*/ REMOVE THIS LINE
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 25px;
 }
```

And if you want the title of the project trigger the function just change that selector and instead of `children` use `next`:

```js
var allPanels = $('.project-name-block-container');
$('.project-name-title').click(function() {
  allPanels.slideUp();
  $(this).next('.project-name-block-container').slideDown();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#project-section-container {
  height: auto;
}
.project-name-block {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.project-name-title {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.project-name-description {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.project-image-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px 5%;
}
.project-img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
.project-name-block-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 1</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 1</div>
    <div class="project-image-container">
      <img src="images/projects/project1.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
      <img src="images/projects/project2.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 2</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 3</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 4</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 5</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**Additional:**

As an improvement to your actual code and if you want to "toggle" the element check this snippet:

```js
$('.project-name-title').click(function() {
  var relative = $(this).next('.project-name-block-container');
  if (!relative.hasClass('opened')) {
    $('.opened').slideUp().removeClass('opened');
    relative.addClass('opened').slideDown();
  } else {
    relative.slideUp().removeClass('opened');
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
#project-section-container {
  height: auto;
}
.project-name-block {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.project-name-title {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.project-name-description {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.project-image-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px 5%;
}
.project-img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
.project-name-block-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 1</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 1</div>
    <div class="project-image-container">
      <img src="images/projects/project1.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
      <img src="images/projects/project2.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 2</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 3</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 4</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
  <div class="project-name-title">Project 5</div>
  <div class="project-name-block-container">
    <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to add the `.hide()` at the end of the `allPanels` variable, but other than that it works great. One other thing, how would I go about being able to close an opened panel without having to click on a different selection? ie: Panel 1 is open, if I click on panel 1 title, it would close.

Comment: @Becky I replace that hide ... with CSS just for personal preferences. Let me ellaborate your requirement.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. You had `display:none` on the `project-name-description` div, which left nothing to display.

```js
var allPanels = $('.project-name-block-container').hide();
//$('.project-name-block:eq(0) .project-name-description').show();
$('.project-name-title').click(function() {   
  allPanels.slideUp();
  $(this).parent().find('.project-name-block-container').slideDown();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.project-name-description{font-size:3rem;}
#project-section-container {
 height: auto;
}
.project-name-block {
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 50px 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.project-name-title {
 color: blue;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.project-name-description {
 XXdisplay: none;
 font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
/*.project-name-description.active {
 display: block;
}*/
/*--Project Images---*/
.project-image-container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 50px 5%;
}
.project-img {
 width: 30%;
 height: auto;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-name-block">
 <div class="project-name-title">Project 1</div>
 <div class="project-name-block-container">
  <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 1</div>
  <div class="project-image-container">
   <img src="images/projects/project1.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
   <img src="images/projects/project2.jpg" alt="Demolition Project" class="project-img">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="project-name-block">
 <div class="project-name-title">Project 2</div>
 <div class="project-name-block-container">
  <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 2</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
 <div class="project-name-title">Project 3</div>
 <div class="project-name-block-container">
  <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 3</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
 <div class="project-name-title">Project 4</div>
 <div class="project-name-block-container">
  <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 4</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="project-name-block">
 <div class="project-name-title">Project 5</div>
 <div class="project-name-block-container">
  <div class="project-name-description">This is the text for Project 5</div>
 </div>
</div>
```